# On Heroku, cannot query certain table and cannot even pull the DB

Tags: deployment, heroku

Since this evening my web app started not working. There was no code change, but suddenly all my requests ends up getting timed out.

At first I thought it was Heroku's problem (They had a brief outage around the time when this started happening), so I waited until Heroku's status came back to normal. But even after it came back to normal pages still wouldn't load.

I tried re-pushing the code, and restarting heroku, etc., but nothing works. Basically, when I do "heroku restart", all the processes DO come back up, but when I try to access the site, the request times out. Here's a list of what's happening:

1. heroku restart => successfully restarts all the processes
2. heroku run console => can successfully connect.
3. on heroku console, try to query table A => works. However another table B takes forever and times out.
4. when accessing a web page via browser, the router successfully receives the request, but nothing happens after that.

What's weird is a query response times out for one table, but for the rest it works. I can't even see what the table looks like so I have no idea what's happening inside. Anyone have this experience? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Last couple of days Heroku had some Shared Database Errors (if you are on Shared database). You can always check status of heroku (timeline) here https://status.heroku.com/.

Also best way is to ask Heroku Support, they are quite agile and fast in responses.